# g++ doesn't link with GLFW

Tags: c++, g++, glfw

I am trying to compile the example program from the glfw page with g++.:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I get undefined references to the glfw functions.
The g++ command:

```
g++ -IGLFW/include -c sample.cpp
```

```
g++ -o sample.exe -LGLFW/lib-mingw-w64 sample.o libglfw3.a
```

The error message:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `_imp__glClear@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd@0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already checked multiplie sources to see if I linked wrong, but to me everything looks right.

My OS is Windows 10

Comment: It sometimes helps, could you quote precisely a sample of your error messages

Comment: `libglfw3.a` --> `-lglfw3` ?